# How to dynamically call a function when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple string formatting app with React, and learning about hooks along the way. I am at the stage now where I want to, when the checkbox is checked, call the corresponding text formatting function.

For example, if the lowercase checkbox is checked, run the formatTextLowerCase function on the input value. If the uppercase checkbox is checked, run the formatTextUpperCase on the input value, and so on. How can I do that?

Keep in mind though that I am already using onChange to limit the number of checkboxes that can be checked at a single time (currently a limit of 1). So I am not sure how I would setup this additional functionality. I am trying to avoid using a bunch of if statements/switch statement to check something like the elements id. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

#### StringFormatter.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';

const StringFormatter = () => {
    const [output, setOutput] = useState('');
    const [checkedBox, setCheckedBox] = useState([]);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const outputRef = useRef(null);

    // get value from input text area
    const getInputValue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        return inputRef.current.value.trim();
    };

    // convert text to lowercase
    const formatTextLowerCase = (text) => text.toLowerCase();

    // convert text to lowercase
    const formatTextUpperCase = (text) => text.toUpperCase();

    // convert text to "web-ready"
    const formatTextWebReady = (text) => {
        return text
            .replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>{}[\]\\/]/g, '')
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
            .toLowerCase();
    };

    // convert text to "PeOPleFucKInGDyINg"
    const formatTextPeopleFuckingDying = (text) => {
        return text
            .split('')
            .map((v) => (Math.round(Math.random()) ? v.toUpperCase() : v.toLowerCase()))
            .join('');
    };

    // limit number of checkboxes checked
    const selectCheck = (e) => {
        const selectedCheckbox = e.target;
        const selectedCheckboxIsChecked = selectedCheckbox.checked;
        const limit = 1;

        if (selectedCheckboxIsChecked) {
            if (checkedBox.length < limit) {
                setCheckedBox((currentState) => [...currentState, selectedCheckbox]);
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.target.checked = false;
            }
        } else {
            // reset to initial state
            setCheckedBox(() => []);
        }
    };

    const displayErrorMessage = (message, duration) => {
        setErrorMessage(message);
        setTimeout(() => setErrorMessage(''), duration);
    };

    // mirror text from input field to output field
    const mirrorText = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // get input value
        // check if input value exists
        // if not, display error message

        const inputValue = getInputValue(e);

        if (!inputValue || checkedBox.length === 0) {
            displayErrorMessage('Please enter a value and/or select a box', 2250);
        } else {
            // if both valid, get function from formattingFn prop
            // use that function to format input value
            // set output value to that formatted value

            console.log(checkedBox);
            console.log(checkedBox.formattingFn);
            console.dir(checkedBox);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form className='formatter'>
            <div className='formatter__row'>
                <div className='formatter__box'>
                    <label className='formatter__label' htmlFor='input'>
                        Input
                    </label>
                    <textarea
                        className='formatter__textarea'
                        name='input'
                        id='input'
                        ref={inputRef}
                    ></textarea>
                    <input className='formatter__button' type='submit' value='Format' onClick={mirrorText} />
                </div>
                <div className='formatter__box'>
                    <span className='formatter__label'>Options (Pick 1)</span>
                    <Checkbox
                        onChangeFn={selectCheck}
                        identifier='format-lowercase'
                        labelText='all lowercase'
                        formattingFn={formatTextLowerCase}
                    />
                    <Checkbox
                        onChangeFn={selectCheck}
                        identifier='format-uppercase'
                        labelText='ALL UPPERCASE'
                        formattingFn={formatTextUpperCase}
                    />
                    <Checkbox
                        onChangeFn={selectCheck}
                        identifier='format-web-ready'
                        labelText='web-ready'
                        formattingFn={formatTextWebReady}
                    />
                    <Checkbox
                        onChangeFn={selectCheck}
                        identifier='format-people-fucking-dying'
                        labelText='PeOPleFucKInGDyINg'
                        formattingFn={formatTextPeopleFuckingDying}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='formatter__row'>
                <div className='formatter__box'>
                    <label className='formatter__label' htmlFor='output'>
                        Output
                    </label>
                    <textarea
                        className='formatter__textarea'
                        name='output'
                        id='output'
                        ref={outputRef}
                        value={output}
                        readOnly={true}
                    ></textarea>
                    <button className='formatter__button'>Copy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {errorMessage && <p className='formatter__error'>{errorMessage}</p>}
        </form>
    );
};

export default StringFormatter;
```

#### Checkbox.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Checkbox = ({ onChangeFn, identifier, labelText, formattingFn }) => {
    return (
        <div className='formatter__group'>
            <input
                className='formatter__check'
                type='checkbox'
                name={identifier}
                id={identifier}
                onChange={onChangeFn}
            />
            <label className='formatter__check-label' htmlFor={identifier}>
                {labelText}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Checkbox = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.checked)
  }
  return (
      <div>
          <input
              type='checkbox'
              id={1}
              onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor={1}>
              {value ? 'TEXT'.toLowerCase() : 'TEXT'}
          </label>
      </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Checkbox />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-YMtLFKDKe5a4zi7rJ0y4wdGErKZe3tx7L+AXDTxjNDzkv7jsaNhvumeU1xQvw6UqVwBVmYlO9NhsSuSVPUN/xQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-vN6rbu+vWW4Ck3s6RbLZs+0gRl5PWOZRUqap38gZtsheSqA2zDeI3PCshuxfYx7ytkoFMrmd0gA2sZZeP1RZYQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Is this solution what you want?

Comment: Hi Sergey, no this does not because right away I noticed this causes me to lose the functionality of limiting the number of checkboxes that can be checked at a single time. Thank you for response